Problem with recursion interfering with a for loop iterating over a nested array in JavaScript
I have a function in my JavaScript code which iterates over an array called background_check which has elements which are also arrays. I want to see if any element in this nested array is a 0 (each element is either a 0 or a 1). I do this with a for loop iterating over the array and calling the function recursively if any element is an array.
Here is my code:
function loop_checker(background_check) {
    let loop_condition = false
    let count = background_check.length
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        if (typeof background_check[i] === 'object') {
            let x = loop_checker(background_check[i])
            if (x === true) {
                loop_condition = true
            }
        }
        else if (background_check[i] === 0) {
            loop_condition = true
        }
    }
    return loop_condition

The array in question is background_check = [1, 1, 1, 1, [1, 1, [1, 0]]]
The function iterates over the first four elements fine. It then gets to the i=4 case and iterates over the smaller array. When the new for loop gets to i=2 it iterates over the smallest list. Once it is all done it goes back down the call stack, but once it gets back to the first call of the function, i=4 has changed to i=3 and so it redoes the 5th element. This repeats infinitely; I cannot figure out why this has happened. I think it may be an issue with the scope of the i variable and recursion messing with that, but I am very new to JS.
P.S. sorry if this is poorly or incorrectly formatted, this is my first question. Thanks in advance!

Make i a local variable. You're overwriting it in the recursive call.

In general, all variables should be local unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

for (let i = 0; ...)

Also, once you set loop_condition = true you should just return it, there's no need to keep looping.

I think I would start by assuming true, then return false immediately after finding a 0. You can short-circuit your loop and not have to iterate through everything.

You may want to check out the Array.some() function.
